# Convert a JS Array ìnto HTML Table | Weird <tbody> Tag?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, html-table

When I use this code, all the information is displayed in only one column. Also, if I check with Google Chrome, there are many `<tbody>` tags that were added to table.innerHTML .

http://puu.sh/4oLmM.png

How can I make it so it displays the header and each `content[i]` horizontally?

```
<table id="table1" border=\"5\" cellpadding=\"10\">

<script>
    var table = document.getElementById('table1');
    table.innerHTML = '';

    var header = ['Method','Gp/Exp','Exp/H']

    var content = [
        ['Kill',1,100],
        ['Die',42,1222],
        ['Yo',1,1245]       
    ]


    //Header
    table.innerHTML += '<tr>';
    for(var i in header){
        table.innerHTML += '<th>' + header[i] + '</th>';
    }
    table.innerHTML += '</tr>';

    //Content
    for(var i in content){
        table.innerHTML += '<tr>';
        for(var j in content[i]){
            table.innerHTML += '<td>' + content[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
        table.innerHTML += '</tr>';
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Browsers typically add tbody tags if the document doesn't supply them.

Comment: Don't set `innerHTML` inside of a loop

Comment: The image link is now dead making the question less clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this is what Ian meant:

```
var html = '<tr>';

for(var i in header){
    html += '<th>' + header[i] + '</th>';
}

html += '</tr>';

for(var i in content){
    html += '<tr>';
    for(var j in content[i]){
        html += '<td>' + content[i][j] + '</td>';
    }
    html += '</tr>';
}

table.innerHTML = html;
```

The way you've done it, you're adding badly formed HTML to the element. The overall string is fine, but my guess is that every time you do `table.innerHTML +=`, it realises that you're creating a dodgy HTML string, and messes around with it to get something that is valid HTML.